# How can I extract the password from an installer/self-extracting archive?

Tags: windows, installation, passwords, archiving, self-extracting

I have an installer/self-extracting archive. The executable file has an embedded ZIP archive into it (like many other installers). The ZIP archive is encrypted with a password.

The installer DOES NOT ask for a password in order to install, it just proceeds with the installation. The installer has an embedded encrypted archive in it, but if started by double clicking the installer, no password is requested from the user.

Upon trying to "open" it with 7-Zip as an archive, bypassing the executable part of the file and just trying to open the ZIP archive part, it asks for a password. This question is NOT about bypassing or cracking the encryption, but about finding out an already available password/encryption key. Since the password/encryption key is embedded inside the executable, this is encryption serves the purpose of obfuscation for the archived files and not for actual confidentiality.

How can I find that password? Since the installer is local and doesn't need an internet connection, the password must be in the .exe file and somehow passed as an argument to the ZIP decryption module.

Here are some similar examples of self-extracting without the user having to input the password themselves; my goal is to extract that password:
[Archive Sidestepping: Self-Unlocking Password-Protected RAR](https://www.trustwave.com/en-us/resources/blogs/spiderlabs-blog/archive-sidestepping-self-unlocking-password-protected-rar/), [Attackers switch to self-extracting password-protected archives to distribute email malware](https://www.csoonline.com/article/3677448/attackers-switch-to-self-extracting-password-protected-archives-to-distribute-email-malware.html)

For reference and continuity:

[How can I extract the password from an installer/self-extracting archive?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31982/how-can-i-extract-the-password-from-an-installer-self-extracting-archive): Proper site for the question

[How can I extract the password from an installer/self-extracting archive?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/270825/how-can-i-extract-the-password-from-an-installer-self-extracting-archive): Deleted

Comment: You can't. Any password dependent encryption worth its salt have passwords *salted* (pun intended).

Comment: @ChanganAuto You are absolutely wrong... An executable file/installer NEEDS to know the password so that it can decrypt the archive. If the file has the password embedded in it, there MUST be a way to extract it. This is more like obfuscation, since the actual password is shipped along with the archive.

Comment: First definitions: https://www.techtarget.com/searchsecurity/definition/salt This is what I meant in the comment. Second, there are 3 ways to (try to) recover such passwords: Mask attack (useful if you know parts of the password), dictionary attack (self-explanatory) or brute force attack. All test passwords, neither extract it. And in any case, even if possible, it would be unethical to help with this.

Comment: @ChanganAuto A "mask attack" is just a subset of Brite-Force attacks. Also, I am well aware of what a "salt" is. In any case, you contribution here is that it is "unethical"? Not a helpful contribution, at all. Unethical is different from illegal and I did not say that I am trying to do something illegal (or unethical) -you are just assuming. The installer/self-extracting archive could very well me my own and maybe I just forgot the password embedded in the executable.

Comment: it might extract the files to a temp directory somewhere when it runs, you might try checking this when it runs and see if you can copy the files

Comment: Yes, unethical is my opinion. Your question has been flagged so let's see what's the opinion of the moderators.

Comment: @garbb It doesn't.

Comment: Or you could just try running strings command on it and see if there is anything that might be a password. Or try a debugger and search for referenced strings? Or it might happen to be something easy to decompile like .NET and maybe you can decompile it and look for a password?

Comment: @garbb I was thinking about the decompilation approach, too and it seems that the password must be somewhere in there :P

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because i don't think hacking, password cracking is appropriate for this site.

Comment: You are completely misunderstanding how passwords work. There is no reason to store the password in the zip file to "compare" with the password given. What you actually do is take the password supplied by the user and simply attempt to decrypt the data. If the password is right then you will get valid data out, if the password is wrong then you get garbage, either case is detectable using data integrity checks built into the archive format. In no way do you need or want to store the password within the file, the data combined with the password supplied by the person decrypting is enough.

Comment: To be clear, you are correct in saying "An executable file/installer NEEDS to know the password" because it does, but incorrect in thinking that it needs to be held in the file itself. It doesn't. You take the password supplied by the user and attempt decryption. If you get valid decrypted data out then it was the correct password, if you get garbage then it was the wrong password.

Comment: You really shouldn't write "You are absolutely wrong" when you're asking for help and have clearly no idea about the topic. This should be closed or even deleted because of very limited value it provides, as it assumes wrong answer, isn't too clear/accurate and it's also easily googlable.

Comment: @Mokubai I have edited the question to make it clearer. The installer, if run by double clicking it, doesn't ask for a password, which is what makes be believe that the password it embedded in the executable. I only get asked for a password when I try to open the installer as a zip archive. If the installer can decrypt the embedded archive, then it knows the password and supplies it to the decryption module. I am well aware that a password doesn't have to be embedded in the file and, instead, has to be provided by the user. In this case, the installer itself doesn't ask for a password.

Comment: @Destroy666 I have edited the question to make it clearer. I assure you, I have quite a bit of "idea" about the subject, but maybe this was the wrong community to post to, since I think that the question might be more suitable for Stack Overflow or Information Security. Also, I have tried googling and, since I have posted here, it means that I couldn't find an answer. Commenting that something is "absolutely wrong" is okay, since I KNOW that it was wrong.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen The question has been closed, but, I dispute that the question was about password cracking. As per the clarifications in the questions, the password is already present in the file. This is more like un-obfuscating the contents.

Comment: Ask in Reverse Engineering site

Comment: @RohitGupta Thank you for pointing that site out, I didn't know it existed.

Comment: You're not going to be able to get this. The person or company who created this installer, used zip encryption to secure their content which you obviously can't break. They embedded this zipfile in their installer. You will have to reverse engineer that executable to find the password. Given they encrypt the zip package, it is very likely they also made it impossible to reverse engineer the code to retrieve the password. For example, they could have created a reversable encryption and encrypted the password too. Without having the source code, its going to be impossible.

Comment: @LPChip Well, as you said, the password is somewhere in the executable. Obviously, I can't break the encryption. I don't have the source code, but I know that the installer was made with NSIS. I was thinking of a sandbox or something similar that can observe the processes started and the password provided...

Comment: Here are some similar examples of self-extracting without the user having to input the password themselves; my goal is to extract that password:
[Archive Sidestepping: Self-Unlocking Password-Protected RAR](https://www.trustwave.com/en-us/resources/blogs/spiderlabs-blog/archive-sidestepping-self-unlocking-password-protected-rar/), [Attackers switch to self-extracting password-protected archives to distribute email malware](https://www.csoonline.com/article/3677448/attackers-switch-to-self-extracting-password-protected-archives-to-distribute-email-malware.html)

Comment: Long ago there were tools to find the zip password once you have both password-protected zip e and not-password-protected zip file with the same content... and it seems you may have both files. However, the most direct way seems to be executing in track the executable until it operates on the file in question...

Comment: For reference and continuity:


[How can I extract the password from an installer/self-extracting archive?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31982/how-can-i-extract-the-password-from-an-installer-self-extracting-archive): Proper site for the question


[How can I extract the password from an installer/self-extracting archive?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/270825/how-can-i-extract-the-password-from-an-installer-self-extracting-archive): Deleted

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is NO. It is not possible. From [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/33418):

> ZIP files are encrypted with AES-256, and the key is derived using a slow key-derivation function (KDF), which makes bruteforce and dictionary attacks generally infeasible. There are no currently known ways to bypass the encryption.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify. I am aware that the encryption cannot be broken. But, the installer, as I suspect, has the password embedded into it and passes it to the zip decryption module. If the installer is run (e.g., by double clicking), no password is asked for from the user If the installer is opened as a zip archive, THEN it asks for a password.

Comment: "as I suspect" - suspect based on what exactly? Common knowledge is that passwords don't work the way you think, except in poorly coded websites or apps. Do you have any reasonable source that states otherwise for this format?

Comment: @Destroy666 As I have explained in the question, the installer can unpack the archive embedded in it without asking for a password. A password is needed when I try to open the archive but bypass the executable code. That means that the executable code, in this case, is holding the password for the archive. This is a case where encryption is used for obfuscation and it is very commonly used to make it harder to reverse engineer, etc. I was just asking for an easy way to extract the password. As another commenter suggested, I will post this in the Reverse Engineering site.

Comment: You should indeed, but you'll learn pretty much what you learned here anyways.

Comment: @Destroy666 The sources you requested: [Archive Sidestepping: Self-Unlocking Password-Protected RAR](https://www.trustwave.com/en-us/resources/blogs/spiderlabs-blog/archive-sidestepping-self-unlocking-password-protected-rar/), [Attackers switch to self-extracting password-protected archives to distribute email malware](https://www.csoonline.com/article/3677448/attackers-switch-to-self-extracting-password-protected-archives-to-distribute-email-malware.html)

Comment: What's that for? That's about malware inside self-extracting archives. No mention about finding out their password. It even says "provided password"...

Comment: @Destroy666 The articles say that the user DIDN'T have to provide the password for the self-extracting archive. The articles say that the password is provided by one of the executables, i.e., the password is hardcoded in the executable. So, the password is IN THE FILE, so that it can be self-unlocking. My goal is to locate the password within the file. The point of doing it is to obfuscate/hide the files and not to make them confidential, since the password can be found out by inspecting the file. I just want to know how to do that.

Comment: Yes, hackers can create own executables or scripts that help with entering the password, which they obviously know. They could also very well make it passwordless, but I assume this is just to get around some antiviruses, possibly.; It's quite irrelevant for a random archive that you or whoever created with 7-zip or whatever.

Comment: @Destroy666 The installer/self-extracting archive I am working with has something similar to the script you mentioned. Now, within the 500MB file, I would like to locate the script (or similar) that enters the password and find the password from the script (or similar) itself... That's what this question is about, but many users misunderstood it... Also, these obfuscation practices are not necessarily just for "hackers".